# rails sort_by method in descending and offset limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

i just wondering do offset limit and ordering by descending in my custom method rails after i called sort_by total_like method. 
this is my custom method in model

```
 class Post < ApplicationRecord
 def total_like
    self.likeposts.count
 end
 ... more code ...
```

and this is script when i tried to calling post that sort by total_like in descending

```
    if POST==@current_entity
            @entities=[]
            @entity.where(paramshash).sort_by(&:total_like).reverse!.each.with_index do |entity, index|
              if index >= params[:offset].to_i && index <= params[:offset].to_i + params[:limit].to_i
                @entities << entity
              end
            end
    render json: @entities
```

can anyone make it simply and does'nt need to call all the record in my Post table :(

Comment: Can you please post how the association between `post` and `likeposts` are defined and how the tables are named?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
Post
  .joins(:likeposts)
  .group('posts.id')
  .order('COUNT(likeposts.id) DESC')
  .offset(params[:offset])
  .limit(params[:limit])
```